Solution of the quadratic equation including floor function.
Let $f(x)=x^2 + (x - \lfloor x\rfloor)*\lfloor x\rfloor - 5$. I wonder that how to solve the equation $f(x)=0$. Is there a theorem that tells whether the equation has a solution?
Thanks.

Find solutions (if any) in $[n,n+1)$ for each $n$.

Let $x=n+r$ where $n=\lfloor x\rfloor$.

Hmm. Perhaps you could first observe that $0<\lfloor x \rfloor<1$. Now you have some possible ranges for the zeros. For example, there aren't any roots in $|x|>3$.

I think you meant ${x}$ since the inequality you use is never true. @MattiP.

Let $x=n+r$ where $n\in I$ and $r\in[0,1)$
$f(x)=0 \implies n^2+r^2+3nr-5=0$
assuming a quadratic in $r$ and applying quadratic formula gives:
$r={-3n\pm\sqrt{5n^2+20}\over2}$
Let $g_1(x)={-3x+\sqrt{5x^2+20}\over2}$ and $g_2(x)={-3x-\sqrt{5x^2+20}\over2}$
so we need to find integer $x$ such that either $g_1(x)$ or $g_2(x)\in[0,1)$
$g_1(x)\in[0,1)$ for $x\in(1,2.236]$ so $n=2, r=g_1(2)\approx 0.162$ so one of the solutions of $f(x)$ is $x\approx 2.162$
$g_2(x)\in[0,1)$ for $x\in(-4,-2.236]$ so $n=-3, r=g_2(3)\approx 0.469$ so another solution of $f(x)$ is $x\approx -2.531$
So, $f(x)$ has 2 solutions.

To be more precise the positive solution is $\sqrt{10}-1$ and the negative one is $\frac{3-\sqrt{65}}2$.
